# MSI GS 60 Fn+F2 (screen mode) and Fn-F10 (airplane mode) not working

Tags: wireless, keyboard, bluetooth, screen, function-keys

I'm under Ubuntu 14.10 with a MSI GS60 2PE.

All my <kbd>Fn</kbd> functions are working except 2 :

- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> : which allow screen mode change
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> : which allow airplane mode (disabling of wifi and bluetooth)

I've tried to see if there's any reaction while running xev but it's like I'm not pressing any buttons.

Dmesg does not show anything too.